# Spherical coordinates plot in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm just starting with pyqtgraph and I want to make 3d surface plots in spherical coordinates. I've taken a look at the example GLSurfacePlot.py from the documentation but there are only plots in cartesian coordinates.

This is the plot I want to make (it's a half wave dipole radiation pattern):

[image]

How to plot r(theta, phi) with pyqtgraph?

**EDIT:** I could do it with matplotlib mplot3d, here is the script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

k = 2*np.pi
long = 0.5
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 361)
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 361)
PHI, THETA = np.meshgrid(phi, theta)
R = np.absolute((np.cos(k*long/2*np.cos(THETA))-np.cos(k*long/2))/np.sin(THETA))
R = np.nan_to_num(R)
X = R * np.sin(THETA) * np.cos(PHI)
Y = R * np.sin(THETA) * np.sin(PHI)
Z = R * np.cos(THETA)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
plot = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10, facecolors=cmap(R),linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha=1)

plt.show()
```

The problem is that it's too slow when rotating and zooming it, and I definitely need that feature for my application, that's why I'm trying to do it with pyqtgraph.

Comment: You could place the mathematical equation

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean what is the equation `r(theta, phi)` without using code.

Comment: Done, I wanted to insert an image containing the mathematical expresion but I can't since I don't have 10 repuation.

Comment: Upload it to dropbox, drive or similar and share the link here, I will place it in your post. :P

Comment: Here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d05wis5uc6jnqpy/equ.gif?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing this type of equations is not possible through [`GLSurfacePlotItem`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/3dgraphics/glsurfaceplotitem.html), in this case you must use [`GLMeshItem`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/3dgraphics/glmeshitem.html), but for this you must create an appropriate [`MeshData`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/3dgraphics/meshdata.html), so it takes as a reference [`sphere`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/3dgraphics/meshdata.html#pyqtgraph.opengl.MeshData.sphere) obtaining the following function:

```
def DipoleData(rows, cols, func, args=None):
    verts = np.empty((rows+1, cols, 3), dtype=float)
    phi = (np.arange(rows+1) * 2*np.pi *(1+2/rows)/ rows).reshape(rows+1, 1)
    th = ((np.arange(cols) * np.pi / cols).reshape(1, cols)) 

    if args is not None:
        r = func(th, phi, *args)
    else:
        r = func(th, phi)
    s =  r* np.sin(th)
    verts[...,2] = r * np.cos(th)
    verts[...,0] = s * np.cos(phi)
    verts[...,1] = s * np.sin(phi)

    verts = verts.reshape((rows+1)*cols, 3)[cols-1:-(cols-1)]  ## remove redundant vertexes from top and bottom
    faces = np.empty((rows*cols*2, 3), dtype=np.uint)
    rowtemplate1 = ((np.arange(cols).reshape(cols, 1) + np.array([[0, 1, 0]])) % cols) + np.array([[0, 0, cols]])
    rowtemplate2 = ((np.arange(cols).reshape(cols, 1) + np.array([[0, 1, 1]])) % cols) + np.array([[cols, 0, cols]])
    for row in range(rows):
        start = row * cols * 2 
        faces[start:start+cols] = rowtemplate1 + row * cols
        faces[start+cols:start+(cols*2)] = rowtemplate2 + row * cols
    faces = faces[cols:-cols]  ## cut off zero-area triangles at top and bottom

    ## adjust for redundant vertexes that were removed from top and bottom
    vmin = cols-1
    faces[faces<vmin] = vmin
    faces -= vmin  
    vmax = verts.shape[0]-1
    faces[faces>vmax] = vmax

    return gl.MeshData(vertexes=verts, faces=faces)
```

It is then used in the following example:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = gl.GLViewWidget()
w.opts['distance'] = 3
w.show()
w.setWindowTitle('Half Wave Dipole Radiation Pattern')

def r_theta_phi(theta, phi, k, l):
    return np.absolute((np.cos((k*l/2)*np.cos(theta)) -np.cos(k*l/2))/np.sin(theta))

p = 2*np.pi
q = 0.5

md = DipoleData(100, 100, r_theta_phi, args=(p, q))
colors = np.ones((md.faceCount(), 4), dtype=float)
colors[:,0] = np.linspace(0.1, 0.2, colors.shape[0])
colors[:,1] = np.linspace(0.2, 0.9, colors.shape[0])
colors[:,2] = np.linspace(0.0, 0.1, colors.shape[0])
md.setFaceColors(colors)
m = gl.GLMeshItem(meshdata=md, smooth=False)
w.addItem(m)

ax = gl.GLAxisItem()
ax.setSize(100,100,100)
w.addItem(ax)

g = gl.GLGridItem()
g.scale(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
w.addItem(g)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Obtaining what is shown in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, it's quite different from what it should look like. http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/norm3D1lam.jpg

Comment: You can tell me the book please, maybe the equation you passed me is another, I am an electronica student and I have simulated it in other programs and I get something similar. :P

Comment: Antenna Theory: Analysis and Design. Constantine A. Balanis. (pages 182-183). Here you can have a look at a capture I made of it:
https://gyazo.com/467868b5353b8eb1d8fb7b35f6d4833b. I only care about the normalized magnitude, so I'm taking the expression within the brackets. It's a simpler expression than the one I passed you because it already has the values k and l substituted. I plotted it with matplotlib mplot3d and got the expected graph, but it's too slow, that's why I want to use pyqtgraph.

Comment: @Jorge The problem is by using the coordinate system, use your definitions I get the same as you.

Comment: Now it looks nice, however, the surface generated isn't completely closed, it has a small opening at phi = 0. Nothing too serious, maybe you could solve it easily. As a beginner, this kind of manipulation looks a bit too complicated to me, I mean, the matplotlib code is so simple compared to this. I'm thinking about trying mayavi as it looks easier.

Comment: @Jorge Is that pyqtgraph is not oriented to that particular type of graphs so there is no direct function to do what you want, I will correct that point but for acknowledging my effort and mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Can you recommend me another 3D plotting utility/library that works with pyqt5? I tried mayavi and it's fanastic but it only supports pyqt4. I've read things about Vispy, VisVis, Glumpy but I'm not sure if any of those can handle the type of graphs I need.

Comment: Use vispy, example:https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/45964913-how-to-embed-vispy-canvas-in-pyqt5-frame

Comment: Is it easier/better than pyqtgraph for my purpose? I mean, if pyqtgraph is the best choice I got, I can stay with it. Later I would also like to add stuff like axis, text, annotations, etc like this: https://gyazo.com/05037ee455f4a935256e30b5be2eedc5

Comment: With pyqtgraph or vispy can do the image, you just have to try. :P

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to set a colormap based on R (with pyqtgraph)? Like I did with matplotlib.

Comment: It has to be created manually, there is no such function in pyqtgraph.